# How to keep keyboard input for Bootstrap datetimepicker?

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to use Bootstrap datetimepicker and it works well, however, there is a problem that I need to resolve. When a date was already chosen, I would like to be able to type keyboard input and to keep that whatever it is, even if it's not a valid date on focus loss.

This is a minimal reproducible example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                    format: "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A",
                    keepOpen: false,
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qfn6mz9t/2/

Reproduction steps:
- choose a date
- click into the input
- type any text, for example "example"
- click outside the input
- the input has something else as a value than what I typed

How to ensure that my input stays even if focus is lost?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the issue. This is how I initialize a datetimepicker:

```
$('#start_date').datetimepicker({
    format: "MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A",
    keepOpen: false,
    useCurrent: false,
    keepInvalid: true,
    useStrict: true
});
```

The `keepInvalid` part is helpful here. I have also needed to replace the `datetimepicker-input` class with `datetimepicker` class, because for some reason invalid dates resulted in stackoverflow exceptions thrown. Now, the new problem was that on focus loss the `datetimepicker` will not close, so I had to programmatically make sure that it closes:

```
function hideDateTimePicker() {
    $("#" + this.id).datetimepicker("hide");
}
```

and

```
$("#start_date, #end_date").on("focusout", hideDateTimePicker);
```